# In eclipse, How to call a function read from the console?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, console

I want to read a function's name from the console, and then calling it in that class.
So, instead of checking which function it is using the "IF" statement, I wish it to happen automatically.

```
Exmp.  
_ (CONSOLE)  
BuildDatabase (WRITTEN IN CONSOLE)  
---> What happens in class : Class.BuildDataBase();
```

Can it be done?
Another question - how can I run my class' main from a command line?

Thanks ahead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection for that:

```
Method method = YourClass.getMethod(nameReadFromConsole); //no parameters
method.invoke(null); // invoking without a target object - i.e. static
```

Running from console is done via the [`java` command](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html) - `java ClassName`

Answer (score 0):

when u say command line do u mean the terminal?
if you want to run the main method inside a class u can just call this:

```
java MyClass
```

But must be the compiled file(the .class)

Answer (score 0):

or you can write a custom reader for your console (this code needs to be cleaned/refactored):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyClass instance = new MyClass();
    while(true) {
       System.out.print("> ");
       String input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
       Method method = MyClass.getDeclaredMethod(input);
       Object returnValue = method.invoke(instance);
       System.out.println(returnValue);
    }
}
```

- Edited to add the 'readLine' call!

Comment: What if I want to pass parameters?